# How can I change label colors in a colored chart?

Tags: plotting, color

I am trying to make a chart with labels, but I would like for the labels on the chart to be white for purposes of visibility.

I am aware of the `Style[expression, White]` option, but when I apply it, my labels go away entirely.

[image: Bad Image]

Code is thus:

```
snp = Log10[Delete[data[[All, 4]], 1]];
BarChart[snp, 
  PlotLabel -> "Plot of Single Nucleotide Polymorphisms", 
  ChartLabels -> Placed[names, Center, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &], 
  ChartStyle -> "LightTemperatureMap", 
  ChartLegends -> names]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
names = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
snp = Log10[data];
BarChart[snp, PlotLabel -> "Plot of Single Nucleotide Polymorphisms", 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[Style[#, Blue, 15] & /@ names, Center, 
                       Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &], ChartStyle -> "TemperatureMap", 
 ChartLegends -> names]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you so much! That solves it!